# cocos2d-x flash import crash

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I wanted to use flash with cocos2d using this example.

https://github.com/splhack/Hello-LWF-Cocos2d-x

I compiled it and run it for android but after first screen appear i receive a crash :

```
create rendererRecreatedListener for GLProgramState

Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3067 (GLThread 2224)
```

I tested in 2 real android device , result is same.
I dnt know what;s wrong .
If somebody have any experience please help.

*Update* logcat is here:

```
02-18 01:58:09.817: I/ActivityManager(744): Start proc com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx for activity com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity: pid=4680 uid=10770 gids={50770, 9997, 3003} abi=armeabi
02-18 01:58:09.833: I/art(4680): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-18 01:58:09.876: I/art(1224): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 26395(1623KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 18MB/30MB, paused 1.473ms total 31.570ms
02-18 01:58:09.897: V/PhoneStatusBar(891): setLightsOn(true)
02-18 01:58:09.912: I/art(4680): Debugger is no longer active
02-18 01:58:09.924: D/JniHelper(4680): JniHelper::setJavaVM(0xb505c280), pthread_self() = -1224855864
02-18 01:58:09.932: D/main(4680): cocos_android_app_init
02-18 01:58:09.947: D/Cocos2dxActivity(4680): model=Nexus 5
02-18 01:58:09.947: D/Cocos2dxActivity(4680): product=hammerhead
02-18 01:58:09.947: D/Cocos2dxActivity(4680): isEmulator=false
02-18 01:58:09.987: I/Adreno-EGL(4680): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/24/14, 167c270, I68fa98814b
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680): {
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   gl.supports_vertex_array_object: true
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   gl.supports_BGRA8888: false
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   gl.supports_ATITC: true
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   gl.supports_S3TC: false
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   cocos2d.x.version: cocos2d-x 3.3
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   gl.supports_discard_framebuffer: true
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   cocos2d.x.compiled_with_profiler: false
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   gl.supports_PVRTC: false
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   cocos2d.x.build_type: DEBUG
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   gl.renderer: Adreno (TM) 330
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   gl.supports_ETC1: true
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   cocos2d.x.compiled_with_gl_state_cache: true
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   gl.version: OpenGL ES 3.0 V@95.0 AU@  (GIT@I68fa98814b)
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   gl.supports_NPOT: true
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   gl.max_texture_units: 32
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   gl.vendor: Qualcomm
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680):   gl.max_texture_size: 4096
02-18 01:58:10.022: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680): }
02-18 01:58:10.033: I/ActivityManager(744): Displayed com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity: +244ms
02-18 01:58:10.302: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680): create rendererRecreatedListener for GLProgramState
02-18 01:58:10.321: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680): create rendererRecreatedListener for GLProgramState
02-18 01:58:10.322: D/cocos2d-x debug info(4680): create rendererRecreatedListener for GLProgramState
02-18 01:58:10.394: A/libc(4680): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4721 (GLThread 434)
02-18 01:58:10.495: I/DEBUG(179): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-18 01:58:10.495: I/DEBUG(179): Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:5.0.1/LRX22C/1602158:user/release-keys'
02-18 01:58:10.495: I/DEBUG(179): Revision: '11'
02-18 01:58:10.495: I/DEBUG(179): ABI: 'arm'
02-18 01:58:10.496: I/DEBUG(179): pid: 4680, tid: 4721, name: GLThread 434  >>> com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx <<<
02-18 01:58:10.496: I/DEBUG(179): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
02-18 01:58:10.580: I/DEBUG(179):     r0 00000000  r1 00001271  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
02-18 01:58:10.580: I/DEBUG(179):     r4 a33ffdb8  r5 00000006  r6 00000002  r7 0000010c
02-18 01:58:10.580: I/DEBUG(179):     r8 6ffeb320  r9 ac497000  sl 00000000  fp a33feeb4
02-18 01:58:10.580: I/DEBUG(179):     ip 00001271  sp a33fedb8  lr b6f6daf9  pc b6f90c24  cpsr 600f0010
02-18 01:58:10.581: I/DEBUG(179): backtrace:
02-18 01:58:10.581: I/DEBUG(179):     #00 pc 00039c24  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
02-18 01:58:10.581: I/DEBUG(179):     #01 pc 00016af5  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
02-18 01:58:10.581: I/DEBUG(179):     #02 pc 00017707  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
02-18 01:58:10.581: I/DEBUG(179):     #03 pc 00013f75  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
02-18 01:58:10.581: I/DEBUG(179):     #04 pc 00012a3c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
02-18 01:58:10.581: I/DEBUG(179):     #05 pc 008976f9  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()+224)
02-18 01:58:10.581: I/DEBUG(179):     #06 pc 008676f7  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())+2)
02-18 01:58:10.581: I/DEBUG(179):     #07 pc 00867727  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::terminate()+10)
02-18 01:58:10.581: I/DEBUG(179):     #08 pc 0086761f  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (__cxa_throw+110)
02-18 01:58:10.581: I/DEBUG(179):     #09 pc 00896f4d  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so
02-18 01:58:10.582: I/DEBUG(179):     #10 pc 00402e14  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__detail::_Compiler<char const*, std::regex_traits<char> >::_M_atom()+852)
02-18 01:58:10.582: I/DEBUG(179):     #11 pc 004010f4  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__detail::_Compiler<char const*, std::regex_traits<char> >::_M_term()+48)
02-18 01:58:10.583: I/DEBUG(179):     #12 pc 003fe880  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__detail::_Compiler<char const*, std::regex_traits<char> >::_M_alternative()+20)
02-18 01:58:10.583: I/DEBUG(179):     #13 pc 003fe8c8  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__detail::_Compiler<char const*, std::regex_traits<char> >::_M_alternative()+92)
02-18 01:58:10.583: I/DEBUG(179):     #14 pc 003fe8c8  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__detail::_Compiler<char const*, std::regex_traits<char> >::_M_alternative()+92)
02-18 01:58:10.583: I/DEBUG(179):     #15 pc 003fe8c8  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__detail::_Compiler<char const*, std::regex_traits<char> >::_M_alternative()+92)
02-18 01:58:10.583: I/DEBUG(179):     #16 pc 003fe8c8  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__detail::_Compiler<char const*, std::regex_traits<char> >::_M_alternative()+92)
02-18 01:58:10.584: I/DEBUG(179):     #17 pc 003fe8c8  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__detail::_Compiler<char const*, std::regex_traits<char> >::_M_alternative()+92)
02-18 01:58:10.584: I/DEBUG(179):     #18 pc 003fe8c8  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__detail::_Compiler<char const*, std::regex_traits<char> >::_M_alternative()+92)
02-18 01:58:10.584: I/DEBUG(179):     #19 pc 003fbd5c  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__detail::_Compiler<char const*, std::regex_traits<char> >::_M_disjunction()+20)
02-18 01:58:10.584: I/DEBUG(179):     #20 pc 003f7c80  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__detail::_Compiler<char const*, std::regex_traits<char> >::_Compiler(char const* const&, char const* const&, std::regex_traits<char>&, unsigned int)+344)
02-18 01:58:10.584: I/DEBUG(179):     #21 pc 003f3bb8  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::shared_ptr<std::__detail::_Automaton> std::__detail::__compile<char const*, std::regex_traits<char> >(char const* const&, char const* const&, std::regex_traits<char>&, unsigned int)+56)
02-18 01:58:10.584: I/DEBUG(179):     #22 pc 003f0e08  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::basic_regex<char, std::regex_traits<char> >::basic_regex(char const*, unsigned int)+116)
02-18 01:58:10.585: I/DEBUG(179):     #23 pc 003ebe50  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so
02-18 01:58:10.585: I/DEBUG(179):     #24 pc 003ee0c4  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::LWFResourceCache::addImage(char const*)+88)
02-18 01:58:10.585: I/DEBUG(179):     #25 pc 004a847c  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (LWF::LWFBitmap::initWithFileEx(char const*, LWF::Format::Texture const&, LWF::Format::TextureFragment const&, LWF::Format::BitmapEx const&)+44)
02-18 01:58:10.585: I/DEBUG(179):     #26 pc 004a8120  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (LWF::LWFBitmap::create(char const*, LWF::Format::Texture const&, LWF::Format::TextureFragment const&, LWF::Format::BitmapEx const&)+88)
02-18 01:58:10.585: I/DEBUG(179):     #27 pc 004a96a8  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer::LWFBitmapRenderer(LWF::LWF*, LWF::Bitmap*, cocos2d::LWFNode*)+972)
02-18 01:58:10.585: I/DEBUG(179):     #28 pc 0049fa24  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN3LWF17LWFBitmapRendererEE9constructIS2_IRPNS1_3LWFERPNS1_6BitmapERPN7cocos2d7LWFNodeEEEEvPT_DpOT0_+120)
02-18 01:58:10.586: I/DEBUG(179):     #29 pc 0049f7f0  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZNSt16allocator_traitsISaIN3LWF17LWFBitmapRendererEEE12_S_constructIS1_IRPNS0_3LWFERPNS0_6BitmapERPN7cocos2d7LWFNodeEEEENSt9enable_ifIXsrNS3_18__construct_helperIT_IDpT0_EEE5valueEvE4typeERS2_PSH_DpOSI_+84)
02-18 01:58:10.586: I/DEBUG(179):     #30 pc 0049f420  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZNSt16allocator_traitsISaIN3LWF17LWFBitmapRendererEEE9constructIS1_IRPNS0_3LWFERPNS0_6BitmapERPN7cocos2d7LWFNodeEEEEDTcl12_S_constructfp_fp0_spcl7forwardIT0_Efp1_EEERS2_PT_DpOSF_+84)
02-18 01:58:10.586: I/DEBUG(179):     #31 pc 0049ee18  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer, std::allocator<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)1>::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<LWF::LWF*&, LWF::Bitmap*&, cocos2d::LWFNode*&>(std::allocator<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer>, LWF::LWF*&&&, LWF::Bitmap*&&&, cocos2d::LWFNode*&&&)+200)
02-18 01:58:10.586: I/DEBUG(179):     #32 pc 0049e8f4  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt23_Sp_counted_ptr_inplaceIN3LWF17LWFBitmapRendererESaIS3_ELNS_12_Lock_policyE1EEE9constructIS6_IKS4_RPNS2_3LWFERPNS2_6BitmapERPN7cocos2d7LWFNodeEEEEvPT_DpOT0_+144)
02-18 01:58:10.586: I/DEBUG(179):     #33 pc 0049e2a8  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZNSt16allocator_traitsISaISt23_Sp_counted_ptr_inplaceIN3LWF17LWFBitmapRendererESaIS2_ELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE1EEEE12_S_constructIS6_IKS3_RPNS1_3LWFERPNS1_6BitmapERPN7cocos2d7LWFNodeEEEENSt9enable_ifIXsrNS8_18__construct_helperIT_IDpT0_EEE5valueEvE4typeERS7_PSN_DpOSO_+100)
02-18 01:58:10.587: I/DEBUG(179):     #34 pc 0049db18  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZNSt16allocator_traitsISaISt23_Sp_counted_ptr_inplaceIN3LWF17LWFBitmapRendererESaIS2_ELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE1EEEE9constructIS6_IKS3_RPNS1_3LWFERPNS1_6BitmapERPN7cocos2d7LWFNodeEEEEDTcl12_S_constructfp_fp0_spcl7forwardIT0_Efp1_EEERS7_PT_DpOSL_+100)
02-18 01:58:10.587: I/DEBUG(179):     #35 pc 0049d2dc  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)1>::__shared_count<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer, std::allocator<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer>, LWF::LWF*&, LWF::Bitmap*&, cocos2d::LWFNode*&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer*, std::allocator<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer> const&, LWF::LWF*&&&, LWF::Bitmap*&&&, cocos2d::LWFNode*&&&)+152)
02-18 01:58:10.587: I/DEBUG(179):     #36 pc 0049c960  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__shared_ptr<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)1>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer>, LWF::LWF*&, LWF::Bitmap*&, cocos2d::LWFNode*&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer> const&, LWF::LWF*&&&, LWF::Bitmap*&&&, cocos2d::LWFNode*&&&)+120)
02-18 01:58:10.587: I/DEBUG(179):     #37 pc 0049c16c  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::shared_ptr<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer>, LWF::LWF*&, LWF::Bitmap*&, cocos2d::LWFNode*&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer> const&, LWF::LWF*&&&, LWF::Bitmap*&&&, cocos2d::LWFNode*&&&)+92)
02-18 01:58:10.587: I/DEBUG(179):     #38 pc 0049ac00  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::shared_ptr<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer> std::allocate_shared<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer, std::allocator<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer>, LWF::LWF*&, LWF::Bitmap*&, cocos2d::LWFNode*&>(std::allocator<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer> const&, LWF::LWF*&&&, LWF::Bitmap*&&&, cocos2d::LWFNode*&&&)+88)
02-18 01:58:10.588: I/DEBUG(179):     #39 pc 00499f00  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::shared_ptr<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer> std::make_shared<LWF::LWFBitmapRenderer, LWF::LWF*&, LWF::Bitmap*&, cocos2d::LWFNode*&>(LWF::LWF*&&&, LWF::Bitmap*&&&, cocos2d::LWFNode*&&&)+104)
02-18 01:58:10.588: I/DEBUG(179):     #40 pc 00498b98  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (LWF::LWFRendererFactory::ConstructBitmap(LWF::LWF*, int, LWF::Bitmap*)+56)
02-18 01:58:10.588: I/DEBUG(179):     #41 pc 004a3f74  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (LWF::Bitmap::Bitmap(LWF::LWF*, LWF::Movie*, int)+208)
02-18 01:58:10.588: I/DEBUG(179):     #42 pc 0047fe34  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN3LWF6BitmapEE9constructIS2_IRPNS1_3LWFEKPNS1_5MovieERiEEEvPT_DpOT0_+120)
02-18 01:58:10.588: I/DEBUG(179):     #43 pc 0047f96c  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZNSt16allocator_traitsISaIN3LWF6BitmapEEE12_S_constructIS1_IRPNS0_3LWFEKPNS0_5MovieERiEEENSt9enable_ifIXsrNS3_18__construct_helperIT_IDpT0_EEE5valueEvE4typeERS2_PSE_DpOSF_+84)
02-18 01:58:10.588: I/DEBUG(179):     #44 pc 0047f3a4  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZNSt16allocator_traitsISaIN3LWF6BitmapEEE9constructIS1_IRPNS0_3LWFEKPNS0_5MovieERiEEEDTcl12_S_constructfp_fp0_spcl7forwardIT0_Efp1_EEERS2_PT_DpOSC_+84)
02-18 01:58:10.588: I/DEBUG(179):     #45 pc 0047e95c  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<LWF::Bitmap, std::allocator<LWF::Bitmap>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)1>::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<LWF::LWF*&, LWF::Movie* const, int&>(std::allocator<LWF::Bitmap>, LWF::LWF*&&&, LWF::Movie* const&&, int&&&)+200)
02-18 01:58:10.588: I/DEBUG(179):     #46 pc 0047dde0  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt23_Sp_counted_ptr_inplaceIN3LWF6BitmapESaIS3_ELNS_12_Lock_policyE1EEE9constructIS6_IKS4_RPNS2_3LWFEKPNS2_5MovieERiEEEvPT_DpOT0_+144)
02-18 01:58:10.589: I/DEBUG(179):     #47 pc 0047cdfc  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZNSt16allocator_traitsISaISt23_Sp_counted_ptr_inplaceIN3LWF6BitmapESaIS2_ELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE1EEEE12_S_constructIS6_IKS3_RPNS1_3LWFEKPNS1_5MovieERiEEENSt9enable_ifIXsrNS8_18__construct_helperIT_IDpT0_EEE5valueEvE4typeERS7_PSK_DpOSL_+100)
02-18 01:58:10.589: I/DEBUG(179):     #48 pc 0047bb54  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZNSt16allocator_traitsISaISt23_Sp_counted_ptr_inplaceIN3LWF6BitmapESaIS2_ELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE1EEEE9constructIS6_IKS3_RPNS1_3LWFEKPNS1_5MovieERiEEEDTcl12_S_constructfp_fp0_spcl7forwardIT0_Efp1_EEERS7_PT_DpOSI_+100)
02-18 01:58:10.589: I/DEBUG(179):     #49 pc 0047a5ec  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)1>::__shared_count<LWF::Bitmap, std::allocator<LWF::Bitmap>, LWF::LWF*&, LWF::Movie* const, int&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, LWF::Bitmap*, std::allocator<LWF::Bitmap> const&, LWF::LWF*&&&, LWF::Movie* const&&, int&&&)+152)
02-18 01:58:10.589: I/DEBUG(179):     #50 pc 00478178  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::__shared_ptr<LWF::Bitmap, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)1>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<LWF::Bitmap>, LWF::LWF*&, LWF::Movie* const, int&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<LWF::Bitmap> const&, LWF::LWF*&&&, LWF::Movie* const&&, int&&&)+120)
02-18 01:58:10.589: I/DEBUG(179):     #51 pc 00474658  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::shared_ptr<LWF::Bitmap>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<LWF::Bitmap>, LWF::LWF*&, LWF::Movie* const, int&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<LWF::Bitmap> const&, LWF::LWF*&&&, LWF::Movie* const&&, int&&&)+92)
02-18 01:58:10.589: I/DEBUG(179):     #52 pc 004714a4  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::shared_ptr<LWF::Bitmap> std::allocate_shared<LWF::Bitmap, std::allocator<LWF::Bitmap>, LWF::LWF*&, LWF::Movie* const, int&>(std::allocator<LWF::Bitmap> const&, LWF::LWF*&&&, LWF::Movie* const&&, int&&&)+88)
02-18 01:58:10.589: I/DEBUG(179):     #53 pc 0046e5dc  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::shared_ptr<LWF::Bitmap> std::make_shared<LWF::Bitmap, LWF::LWF*&, LWF::Movie* const, int&>(LWF::LWF*&&&, LWF::Movie* const&&, int&&&)+104)
02-18 01:58:10.589: I/DEBUG(179):     #54 pc 00467fec  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (LWF::Movie::ExecObject(int, int, int, int, int, int, bool)+876)
02-18 01:58:10.589: I/DEBUG(179):     #55 pc 00468978  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (LWF::Movie::PostExec(bool)+1292)
02-18 01:58:10.589: I/DEBUG(179):     #56 pc 0040f224  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (LWF::LWF::ExecInternal(float)+916)
02-18 01:58:10.590: I/DEBUG(179):     #57 pc 0040f4bc  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (LWF::LWF::Exec(float, LWF::Matrix const*, LWF::ColorTransform const*)+248)
02-18 01:58:10.590: I/DEBUG(179):     #58 pc 003e0154  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::LWFNode::update(float)+132)
02-18 01:58:10.590: I/DEBUG(179):     #59 pc 004de94c  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (void cocos2d::Scheduler::scheduleUpdate<cocos2d::Node>(cocos2d::Node*, int, bool)::{lambda(float)#1}::operator()(float) const+56)
02-18 01:58:10.590: I/DEBUG(179):     #60 pc 004e0298  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::_Function_handler<void (float), void cocos2d::Scheduler::scheduleUpdate<cocos2d::Node>(cocos2d::Node*, int, bool)::{lambda(float)#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, float)+60)
02-18 01:58:10.590: I/DEBUG(179):     #61 pc 0058b0dc  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::function<void (float)>::operator()(float) const+88)
02-18 01:58:10.590: I/DEBUG(179):     #62 pc 00587c2c  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Scheduler::update(float)+308)
02-18 01:58:10.590: I/DEBUG(179):     #63 pc 00550a20  /data/app/com.example.hellolwfcocos2dx-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Director::drawScene()+168)
02-18 01:58:11.029: I/DEBUG(179): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_09
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with Android NDK r10d.

```
$ NDK_ROOT=<your-android-ndk-r10d-path> ./build_native.py -n -j8
$ ant -Dsdk.dir=<your-android-sdk-path> debug install
```

I don't have any problems on Android 5.0, Nexus 6 and Nexus 9.

Comment: Thanks , for info , I recompiled it exacly using your 2 commands.I compiled it using Ubuntu .I tested apk on Google Nexus 5 android 5.0 and Galaxy Xcover 2 , android 4.2.1 and still crash.I updated my post with lofgcat message . I think is my ndk version , I dn't know . I use ndk r10b